# Query which finds people in a radius around me

Tags: parse-platform

I want to find users in a radius of 10 km around me. I've got the location of every user in my User db.

I thought I could do it this like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query =
ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereWithinKilometers("location", new ParseGeoPoint(currentLoc.getLatitude(), currentLoc.getLongitude()), 10);
query.setLimit(1);
query.findInBackground(new
    FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.d("Test", "Got result");
            }
            else {
                  Log.d("Test", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }        
);
```

This gives me a nullpointer exception on the linke of e.getMessage. I also think the query can return "myself" as an result and thats not the point. Do I need to give another constraint `like != currentUser`?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem the `if test e!= null` must be `e == null` in the case of this query.

Here the full working query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereWithinKilometers("location", new ParseGeoPoint(currentLoc.getLatitude(), MainActivity.currentLoc.getLongitude()), 10);
query.setLimit(10);
query.whereNotEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null)
        {
            Log.d("Test", "Got results: " + objects.size());
            for(ParseUser it : objects)
                Log.d("Test","User found: " + it.getUsername());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Test", "User not found: " + e.getMessage());
        }    
    }
);
```